# Firebase hosting ssl certificate is showing different domain

Tags: firebase, ssl, https, dns, firebase-hosting

I've connected a custom domain to firebase hosting, you can see placeholder website here: https://asimetriq.com

At first glance everything seems to be fine, but when I view ssl certificate details I see unrelated domain details. Is this normal and if so why is it happening? If not is this a bug on firebase side?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is normal, you should go to the "Details" part to see the whole certificate content.

You will see that the certificate has a "Subject Alternative Name" extension, in which you will find many DNS names, including one for your own website. The certificate applies in the same way to all websites in this list.
This is done to reduce the number of certificates to handle, specifically for servers hosting multiple websites with different names on the same IPs (if you check you will see that all names below resolves to the same set of IPs)

Your browser accepts it because it sees the content in the extension and it sees your website in it. If not, your browser would have say that the connection is insecure because there is a name mismatch between the website name in the URL and what is inside the certificate.

Certificate content:

```
Data:
    Version: 3 (0x2)
    Serial Number:
        03:f7:1d:8f:a5:a2:78:84:8e:5b:eb:f3:45:a9:90:2a:ce:5a
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
    Issuer: C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
    Validity
        Not Before: Apr 21 17:14:16 2018 GMT
        Not After : Jul 20 17:14:16 2018 GMT
    Subject: CN=www.blowwhalestudios.uk

...

    X509v3 extensions:

...

        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
            DNS:1profiremiralomanorco.xyz, DNS:1profiresanbernardino.xyz, DNS:22q11northernireland.co.uk, DNS:71holiday.com, DNS:99idiomas.com.br, DNS:admin.wikifinance.com.au, DNS:agenda.zipper.com.co, DNS:akshayverma.net, DNS:alexpjames.com, DNS:alfreds.com.br, DNS:app.feedmeapp.ca, DNS:app.getpremises.com, DNS:app.givebadges.com, DNS:app.verhuisplan.be, DNS:asimetriq.com, DNS:auth.skillapp.co, DNS:auxglacesdelanse.ca, DNS:bio.apartments, DNS:calendarbuttonz.com, DNS:cammedar.com, DNS:carlan.didrik.tech, DNS:casheep.xyz, DNS:cats.grankullen.se, DNS:chcsecurity.com, DNS:coinsrage.com, DNS:coopearsa.com, DNS:ddnode.com, DNS:deliriumdesigns.com, DNS:dev.heyleap.com, DNS:dev.mundoemprendedor.org, DNS:ecoema.com.co, DNS:gamenightbuddy.com, DNS:gamestatext.com, DNS:gardenpartyfloristmukwonago.com, DNS:go-beeline.com, DNS:gruposafira.com.br, DNS:handcricketgame.com, DNS:heyleap.com, DNS:hoppy.co.uk, DNS:hyperpost.co, DNS:itsupport.conceptplusllc.net, DNS:manager.artus.io, DNS:markato.studio, DNS:mattmc.co.uk, DNS:mips.haoxp.xyz, DNS:my.valuehome.ca, DNS:openmatics.going2.com.br, DNS:opportunityspace.co, DNS:ozcaynalavalle.com.ar, DNS:parkero.se, DNS:paybacks.rocks, DNS:physio-vd.ch, DNS:pokus.severa.name, DNS:portal.gruposafira.com.br, DNS:q.crawlink.com, DNS:rockpepaine.ro, DNS:safetolk.se, DNS:satin.silkypresets.com, DNS:scorecard.curtisrutland.com, DNS:seaportpuntadeleste.com.uy, DNS:secure.pam3.ru, DNS:sendsms.cc, DNS:shiftfirst.ai, DNS:smuldersbram.bramsmulders.com, DNS:superadmin.qulinaryapp.com, DNS:test.keystone-energy.co.uk, DNS:vot.thundersha.work, DNS:www.1profirecorona.xyz, DNS:www.1profiremiralomanorco.xyz, DNS:www.1profiresanbernardino.xyz, DNS:www.256co.com, DNS:www.auxglacesdelanse.ca, DNS:www.bangkokwomensrun.com, DNS:www.blowwhalestudios.uk, DNS:www.calendarbuttonz.com, DNS:www.coopearsa.com, DNS:www.digitalnauts.com, DNS:www.donadafesta.com.br, DNS:www.dot3digital.com, DNS:www.greenpilates.net, DNS:www.happinessisajourney.com, DNS:www.haxor.com, DNS:www.hoppy.co.uk, DNS:www.insulcoat.co.za, DNS:www.juntstrenquembarreres.cat, DNS:www.kakobotasso.com.br, DNS:www.kangsenan.com, DNS:www.letspla.net, DNS:www.mi11er.net, DNS:www.mileageondemand.com, DNS:www.n-studios.tk, DNS:www.narrated.co, DNS:www.physio-vd.ch, DNS:www.sears.ca, DNS:www.shiftfirst.ai, DNS:www.suisse-connect.ch, DNS:www.thinkingandwriting.org, DNS:www.venturehacks.xyz, DNS:www.vivionline.com.br, DNS:www.wizy.vn
```

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that one of those website could impersonate my website after hijacking my customers DNS?

Comment: You externalize your hosting to a company, which handles your certificates. This company can indeed impersonate your website any way it wishes (because as long as your website resolves to their IP address they can use LE http-01 validation challenge to issue certificate for your website name), this does not need any DNS hijacking, it is "normal". The other websites gave control to the hosting company in the same way as you (presumably at some point at least), they won't have any more control than you ("they" need the private key associated to the cert... only the hosting company has it).

Comment: The fact that Firebase hosting issues such certificates makes me want to move to another provider to host my static websites. To a savvy user, such SSL certificates might not seem trustworthy. Personally, I'd prefer `subjectAltName` to contain domains relevant to a single organisation.

Comment: @DmitriLihhatsov I doubt regular user have the habit to study the content of a certificate before going further, they just rely on their browser showing either a green "thing" or a big red error notification in case of certificate problems. So I really do not think those certificates are a problem, and many providers do things the same way for obvious reasons (less certificates to handle). Otherwise if you do not want this, you need to be in control yourself of your certificates, which means probably uploading them yourselves to your provider which has its drawbacks...

Comment: Fair point, @Patrick, I don't expect a regular user to be so picky :) However, Google AppEngine issues managed certificates just fine, GKE also offers managed certificates for Ingress serrvices. Only Firebase hosting decided to cut down on the total number of certificates and bundle them - that's the thing that I don't understand.

Comment: "Only Firebase hosting decided to cut down on the total number of certificates and bundle them" Not just them. At least CloudFlare, on their free SSL product, do exactly the same thing (put unrelated site names in a single certificate). Probably many other providers. Browsers should never have used the certificate subject in the first place, this was set 20 years ago but things move slowly.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek checking now in 2023 cloudflare certifcates have single domain where firebase's still have long list of alternate names. This bothers me a bit as I don't like my private projects being exposed like this. they are obviously well protected but still the anonymity of the domain/subdomain is just an extra layer of protection that is missing here as every curious hacker can start sniffing on these certificates and get a list of active domains they can try and breach where with single certificate and no-index the domain won't show in search-engines and be a little bit more protected

Comment: @atlanteh All of this (how certificates contain names) is irrelevant. ALL certificates are stored and publicly available in the Certificate Transparency Logs and there are multiple websites allowing to search into this. So there is no way to hide and no anonymity there.